# Multivariable calculus proof using gradients

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I need to solve this problem for my vector calculus class but I have no idea how to do it.

Here is the problem:

> Let $f$ be a differentiable function defined in $\mathbb{R^n}$, suppose there is $k>0$ such that $$f(tx)=t^kf(x),\quad \forall x\in \mathbb{R}^n$$
> Prove that $$x\cdot \nabla f(x)=kf(x),\quad \forall x\in \mathbb{R}^n$$
> *Hint: $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ fixed, consider function $g(t)=f(tx)$*

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differentiate both left hand side and right hand side with respect to $t$

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left[t^{k}f(x)\right]&=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\partial(tx_{i})}{\partial t}\frac{\partial}{\partial(tx_{i})}f(tx)\phantom{x}\\
\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial(tx_{i})}f(tx)\\
\\
kt^{k-1}f(x)&=x\cdot\nabla f(tx)
\end{align}
$$

If we evaluate this expression at $t=1$ we get the desired expression